# mySQL self join table to find single row from max(column) on today's date

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table of high scores that is updated by a script at midnight every day.

Table name: hiscores

```
+-------+-------+---------------------+
| user  | score |        time         |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
| Bob   |   100 | 2017-10-24 00:00:04 |
| Frank |   105 | 2017-10-24 00:00:05 |
| Ahmed |    44 | 2017-10-24 00:00:06 |
| Frank |    77 | 2017-10-25 00:00:04 |
| Bob   |   101 | 2017-10-25 00:00:05 |
| Ahmed |   100 | 2017-10-25 00:00:06 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

I wish to return the user with the highest score placed today.

Assuming today's date is 2017-10-25, result required:

```
| Bob   |   101 | 2017-10-25 00:00:05 |
```

Initially I tried this:

```
SELECT hs.time, hs.user, hs3.high_score
  FROM `hiscores` AS hs

  JOIN (SELECT MAX(hs2.score) AS high_score
          FROM `hiscores` AS hs2
       ) AS hs3
     ON hs.score = hs3.high_score
```

Which returned a single row with the highest score - wrong date/time.

```
| Bob   |   101 | 2017-10-25 00:00:04 |
```

Then I tried:

```
SELECT hs5.hs_time, hs.user, hs3.high_score
  FROM `hiscores` AS hs

  JOIN (SELECT MAX(hs2.score) AS high_score
          FROM `hiscores` AS hs2
       ) AS hs3
     ON hs.score = hs3.high_score

  JOIN(SELECT hs4.time AS hs_time FROM `hiscores` AS hs4) AS hs5
     ON DATE(hs5.hs_time) = DATE(NOW())
```

Which returns the correct user and score but over 3 rows (with all times).

```
| Bob   |   101 | 2017-10-25 00:00:04 |
| Bob   |   101 | 2017-10-25 00:00:05 |
| Bob   |   101 | 2017-10-25 00:00:06 |
```

I have tried a lot of things in between, not just those 2, but they are my closest attempts. I can see the issue, but not how to fix it.

Comment: Break your problem into parts. What would you need in addition to the original to pick rows with the highest score today? Then to get just names? Then to get rid of duplicates? PS What if multiple people have the max today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, you don't need to use join. Just follow this example:

```
SELECT 
   user, score, time 
FROM `hiscores` 
WHERE 
   DATE(time)=CURDATE() AND 
   score=(SELECT MAX(score) FROM `hiscores` WHERE DATE(time)=CURDATE())
```

Comment: for me this returns 3 results with the correct high score - but all users and all scores for that day: bob - 101 - today - 101, ahmned - 100 - today - 101, Frank - 77 - today - 101

Comment: @DJR Note that DATE(time) cannot use an index - in case performance matters

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one solution. Note that this doesn’t account for ties:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE time >= CURDATE() 
 ORDER 
    BY score DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```